# Lift Web, lift:surround with parameters

Tags: parameter-passing, lift

Lift student here.

I'm using `lift:surround?with=template;at=page-body&banner=true`

then in template I have `<head class = "lift:TestSnippet.processHead?banner={BANNER}">`

but I get this error: `Message: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "{BANNER}"`

Setting the parameter in the `body` class I get its correct value: 'true'.

How to set the banner parameter on head class dynamic? If I set `lift:TestSnippet.processHead?banner=true` it works perfect, but not when it is a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand, how do you want the "{BANNER}" to be passed to the snippet? If you write it as pure text then that's a syntax error or just a meaning-less text as parameter..

Note that Lift does not assume any real logic in the HTML -- only invocations of snippets. You can't "remember" any variable in HTML, nor can you pass it with "{BANNER}" / "$BANNER" / ...